# I am unable to see running device option in android studio for flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, ide

This is android studio for android project and I can see running device option to see real device were app is running actually but for flutter project I cant see.
[image]

Below is flutter project android studio view
[image]

I want to see running device option in android studio.

Answer (score 0):

You can see it from the **View** -> **Tool Window** -> **Running Devices**

Current Android Studio Version ***HedgeHog Canaray Release***

**Preview**
[image: preview]